# HTML content into dataTable pdf export

Tags: pdf, datatable

I am trying to show custom HTML content into my exported pdf from Datatable. But unfortunately it just shows raw html.

```
 {
    extend: 'pdf',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    title: "TEST Title",
    messageTop: "<h2>hello world</h2><p> I am just exporting the dataTable as PDF</p>"
  }
```

Is there any way to render html content into header and footer part of pdf export?

Comment: It looks like you are referring to [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). You can therefore use the `datatables` tag. The `datatable` tag is for different uses (hover your mouse over the tag for details).

Comment: What do you mean ? I'am exactly the same issue. I don't understand your answere.

Comment: There is nothing more depressing than finding the question you asked, and then seeing that it is unanswered and has been so for years.